# how to filter out only the subitem from array

Tags: jq

```
{
  "s" : {
    "this_key_might_not_be_known_ahead_of_time" : [
      {
        "service": "c",
        "stack": "c_c",
        "deploymentId": "abc"
      },
      {
        "service": "c",
        "stack": "del_in_pr",
        "deploymentId": "deg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I get the "deployment_id" for only the "stack" which are in "c_c" status.
Note: as the name this_key_might_not_be_known_ahead_of_time suggests, I might not know the key name

The closest I got was `jq -c '.s[] | . - map(select(.stack | contains("c_c"))) | .[] .deploymentId'` but it does the exact opposite of what I want and if I remove the '-' from the query above it does not work

Comment: `jQuery` is a JavaScript library. What does that have to do with `jq`?

Comment: How about `jq -r '.s[][] | select(.stack | contains("c_c")).deploymentId'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.[]` to stream/iterate all values of an object, regardless of their key. You can then use the `map(select(...))` pattern to select only the interesting items from the inner array:

```
.s[] | map(select(.stack=="c_c").deploymentId)
```

Output:

```json
[
  "abc"
]
```